# Wire with current in magnetic field $\vec{B}$has force $\vec{F_1}$. When rotated, $\vec{F_2}$. Find $B$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, vectors

I have the following question:

In a wire with $10cm$ there is a current $4A$ going 'upwards' in the $z$ axis. The force over this field, under a constant magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is $F = -0.2\vec{i} + 0.2\vec{j}$. If the wire is rotated in a way that the current is going 'upwards' in the $x$ axis, then the force over this wire is $F = 0.2\vec{k} N$. Find $\vec{B}$

Well, I know that $F = iL\times B$, so in the first case we have:

$$(-0.2,0.2,0) = iL\times B = (0,0,\frac{4}{10} m)\times(a,b,c) = (-\frac{2b}{5},\frac{2a}{5},0)$$

For the second case:

$$(0,0,0.2) = iL\times B = (0,\frac{4}{10}m, 0)\times (a,b,c) = (\frac{2c}{5},0,-\frac{2a}{5})$$

From these two equations, we get:
$$(-0.2,0.2,0) = (-\frac{2b}{5},\frac{2a}{5},0)$$
$$(0,0,0.2) = (\frac{2c}{5},0,-\frac{2a}{5})$$

which gives:

$$\frac{2b}{5} = 0.2\implies b = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{2a}{5} = 0.2\implies a = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{-2a}{5} = 0.2\implies a = -\frac{1}{2}\color{red}{????}$$
$$\frac{2c}{5} = 0 \implies c = 0$$

As you can see, I have a different $a$ in each equation, so something is wrong. Could somebody help me?

Comment: I think the equation $(0,0,0.2) = (\frac{2c}{5},0,-\frac{2a}{5})$ should be $(0,0,0.2) = (0,-\frac{2c}{5},\frac{2b}{5})$.

Comment: @jim why? I just did these vector products at wolfram alpha

Comment: In the second case you have $I {\bf L} = 0.4 {\bf i}$, then with ${\bf B} = a {\bf i} + b {\bf j} + c {\bf k}$ the quantity $I {\bf L} \times {\bf B} = 0.4a {\bf i}\times{\bf i} + 0.4b {\bf i}\times{\bf j} + 0.4c {\bf i}\times{\bf k}$. Using ${\bf i}\times{\bf i} = 0, {\bf i}\times{\bf j} = {\bf k}, {\bf i}\times{\bf k} = -{\bf j}$ it becomes $-0.4c{\bf j} + 0.4b {\bf k}$.